# Warning `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'

Tags: floats

I know this question was asked many times here but I am still confused. According to several answers, float deals with positioning tables, images etc. I tried to find which figures are wrong position or doesn't fit with my page size. I deleted one by one, until all of them include tables, but I am still facing the warning.

I also got two overfull \hbox messages in several lines. I tried to delete the line, but it remain the same. 
How to fix them?

Or I don't know if it's correlate or not because PdfTex won't execute my page even I don't find error messages

Comment: Just change all your `[!h]` to `[htp]`  you should never use `[!h]` anyway as unless latex changes it and gives the warning that you mention, it gives almost no chance to position the floats.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's just a warning, not an error. The message is *supposed* to be helpful (but it may not succeed...), to explain why some floats appear at the top of the following page instead of on the current page even though `[h!]` was specified. Simply replace all instances of `[h!]` with `[ht!]`, and the warning messages will disappear.

Comment: Yeah, It is just a warning but my page couldn't be executed even I don't find any error message

Comment: @David Carlisle I don't have [!h], all of my figures and tables I set to be [!htb]

Comment: What do you mean by "my page[s] couldn't be executed"?

Comment: I meant I couldn't see the pdf page of my PdfTex page because the program won't execute it.

Comment: if you get the warning message in the title then you have a figure or table with `[!h]`

Comment: Nothing that you have mentioned so far is an error so nothing will stop the pdf output. If a pdf is not being generated than you have an error unrelated to what you have shown so far, if you show no code and do not show the error message from the log it is impossible to guess any help.